# jQuery selector - what is faster?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

$('#content td#foo').show();
    $('td#foo').show();

The td is somewhere deep in the content div.

What is faster?

Comment: Is it possible that there is an element with the ID *foo* that is not a `TD` element? Otherwise use rahul’s advice.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can simply write

```
$("#foo").show();
```

You cannot have more than 1 elements with the same id. So no need to use any additional selector to get an element with a particular id. So your td tag selector can be avoided.

Comment: Fixed the typo. Thanks @fudgey

Answer (score 16):

The fastest is:

```
$('#foo').show();
```

IDs must be unique, this results in a hash table lookup in the browser for the reference to the DOM element, doesn't get any faster than that.  If your ID `foo` isn't unique, you have other problems...that is invalid HTML.

Answer (score 8):

Both of those selectors will resolve to:

```
$('#foo').show();
```

however, the [manual](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) says:

**For id selectors, jQuery uses the JavaScript function document.getElementById(), which is extremely efficient. When another selector is attached to the id selector, such as h2#pageTitle, jQuery performs an *additional check before identifying the element as a match***.

You can think of the aforementioned *additional check* as completely pointless, unless you have duplicate IDs in your markup, which is incorrect in terms of the definition and usage of the HTML ID attribute. See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_id.asp.